# Ninject WCF extention with already existing ServiceHostFactory and ServiceHost

Tags: wcf, ninject, servicehost

We have a difficulty to use Ninject wcf extensions. We host our services in IIS and using svc files. We have read a lot of posts describing usage of `NinjectServiceHostFactory`(in svc files) with `NinjectHttpApplication` (in `global.asax` file) and it seems very simple.
Our problem is that we already have our custom `ServiceHostFactory` and `ServiceHost`.

Can someone point us what is the right way combining our `ServiceHostFactory` with `NinjectServiceHostFactory`?

Our svc files point to the our custom `ServiceHostFactory`.

**UPDATE**

It seems that we managed to implement it.
Our ServiceHostFactory implementation:

```
public class CustomServiceHostFactory : NinjectServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override Type ServiceHostType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CustomServiceHost<>);
        }
    }
}
```

Our ServiceHost implementation:

```
public class CustomServiceHost<T> : NinjectAbstractServiceHost<T>
{
    public CustomServiceHost(IServiceBehavior serviceBehavior, T serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)  : base(serviceBehavior, serviceType, baseAddresses)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override void OnOpening()
    {
        ...

        base.OnOpening();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: The code is really standard. We have our ServiceHostFactory defined in svc files.

Comment: Have you tried to extend `NinjectServiceHostFactory` and put code from your `ServiceHostFactory` there?